# how to determine whether the limit at $z=-i$ exists or not, of complex-valued function $z^2/(z+i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> how to determine whether the limit at $z=-i$ exists or not, of complex-valued function $z^2/(z+i)$?

Consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{z\to -i} \frac{z^2} {z+i}.$$

Does this limit exist ?

What about $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}^2}\;\;?$$

Does this limit exist ?

Comment: For the first case I think you can multiply both numerator and denumerator with $z+i$. In the second case you can just simplify it to get $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z}= \infty$.

Comment: For the first question, can you see what the limit $\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{z^2}{z-1}$ might be? Your question is not different at all. For the second question, what happens when $z$ goes to zero through real values?